# I've written a thread but how do I add it to my main method?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my current code; how can I edit the main method to get it to run?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Virus {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread virus = new Thread();
    }
}

class pop implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    { 
        int x = 1000;
        int y = 1000;

        JFrame popup = new JFrame();
        popup.setLocation(x, y);
        popup.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(popup, "Virus fun time");
    }
}
```

Comment: the import was part of the code too, forgot to indent it was all

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: *"the import was part of the code too, forgot to indent it was all"* There's this tempting "edit" link under the question...

Comment: You can edit your post... (I've done that for you)

Comment: Don't modify, change or create UI components outside the Event dispatching thread!

Answer (score 1):

You're close. A `Runnable` needs a thread to run it, and you pass an instance of the `Runnable` into the thread. So using the [`Thread(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) constructor:

```
Thread virus = new Thread(new pop());
```

Then you [*start*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) the thread:

```
virus.start();
```

Then you need to wait for it to finish, via [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29):

```
virus.join();
```

(You'll need to handle the exception that may throw.)

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) may help you with these fundamentals.

***But***, heed what @MadProgrammer commented on the question:

> Don't modify, change or create UI components outside the Event dispatching thread!

[This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) may help you there.

Comment: Are you missing a start somewhere? :D

Comment: @Avempace: Went back to add links, and thought...hmmm, don't seem to have started it. :-)

Comment: @DavidKnipe: That won't run it on its own thread. If the goal were to run it on the same thread, you wouldn't use `Runnable`.